# Translating big amount of csv file (Flickr8k_text dataset) to 'Nepali' Language in python

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, google-translate

I've been working in a Image Captioning Project in 'Nepali Language'. For Dataset part I tried to translate all the English captions text to Nepali of the Flickr8k dataset. For this I'm using python `translate` tool as

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/out.csv',delimiter = '\t')
dataset.drop('Unnamed: 0',axis = 1)
def trans(x):
    translator= Translator(to_lang="ne")
    return translator.translate(x)
dataset['caption'] = dataset['caption'].apply(trans)
print('done')
```

But it only translated 130 rows of captions to Nepali language and then all other texts are translated as

MYMEMORY WARNING: YOU USED ALL AVAILABLE FREE TRANSLATIONS FOR TODAY. NEXT AVAILABLE IN  23 HOURS 24 MINUTES 38 SECONDSVISIT  TO TRANSLATE MORE

**Is there's any way of translating all the texts at once??**

I've tried googletrans too but it also fails due to frequent request on API

Note: the dataset contains 40458 rows with English sentences in caption column.

It will be great help if there's any way to translate all the text and Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out by myself. Use google sheet and import your csv file
and make a column with the header named the target language's name and use the formula `=googletranslate(cell_with_text, "source_language", "target_language")`

example: `=googletranslate(A2,"en","ne")` now from the corner of the cell where mouse pointer appears as + like sign and drop all the way down and bingo you can translate all the text in a column at once.